# Issues regarding SVN folders and good repository name

Tags: svn, repository-design, svn-repository

I am a little bit confused how SVN related settings should be configured assuming I want to use SVN on my local machine. They are as below:

1. Are the folders -- trunk, branch and tag -- created by default or do we need to introduce it ourselves (like using mkdir command on UNIX)?
2. Is it a good practice to name our repository as `svn` or can it be any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)  No, the `trunk,branches,tags` directories are not automatic or even required. That particular directory heirarchy is just a common practice and you must create each directory yourself via `svn mkdir`.  If you are on a Unix system with a Bash shell, you can do it in one go:

```
 svn mkdir file:///your/svn/repo/projectname/{trunk,tags,branches}
```

2) Your repository name is completely arbitrary. Name it whatever you want.